# Session cookie not created - Play 2.5

Tags: scala, session, cookies, playframework

I've installed new Play 2.5.0. The framework is surely promising, however the documentation is scarce. I've created and run a new application. However, for some reason it doesn't create a session cookie out-of-the-box, and it's not clear how to initialize a session with PLAY_SESSION initialized. Can someone advise how to work with sessions in Play 2.5 using Scala. Particularly, should the session cookie be created by default by a new app, and how to create it in custom code.

Answer (score -1):

Figured this out: session cookie is not set by default.

Comment: and what is the solution?